# How to moq the LinkQ extionsion method

Tags: moq

How to moq the OfType to return

```
class A
{ 
  public void iterate()
  {
    foreach (var aTool in Handler.Tools.OfType<IDrawTool>())
    {
      //some code
    }
  }
}

//tools implementes both interface ITool and IDrawTool
//wanted to get the tool which implements the IDrawTool from the 
//Handler.Tools<ITool> list

Mock<List<ITool>> aToolMockList = new Mock<ITool>();
Mock<IDrawTool> adrawToolMock = new Mock<IDrawTool>();
aToolMockList.Setup(list => list.OfType<IDrawTool>()).Returns((IEnumerable<IDrawTool>)  adrawToolMock .Object);
```

But the `OfType` throws the exception `setup on a non-member method`

Should I override this? What should I do?

Comment: .As() makes casting to the mocked object

Comment: the problem is with this line list => list.OfType<IDrawTool>())

Comment: Best prctice: Not to mock list; make real list and put inside mocks - in this example one for general ITool and one for IDrawingTool; I'll post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ITool> aToolMockList = new List<ITool>();
Mock<IDrawTool> adrawToolMock = new Mock<IDrawTool>();
Mock<ITool> aToolMock = new Mock<ITool>;
//additional setups
aToolMockList.Add(adrawToolMock.object);
aToolMockList.Add(aToolMock.object);
//
A a = new A(aToolMockList);
A.iterate();
//
adrawToolMock.Toolwork.Verify(Times.Once);
aToolMock.Toolwork.Verify(Times.Never);
```

Something like that :)